# SQL Server Procedure Case when I where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that looks simplified like this:

```
begin

select
(
case
    when @Method = 'phone' then u.PhoneNumber
    when @Method = 'email' then u.Email
end
)
from
    Table a
join 
    Users u on a.ID = u.Id
where 
    a.Active = 1
    and

    -- This part does not work
    case 
        when @Method = 'phone' then u.PhoneNumber is not null
        when @Method = 'email' then u.Email is not null
    end
end
```

So the problem is that I don't want null values and both phone and email can be null. So if the @Method parameter is phone, I don't want null values in `u.PhoneNumber` and when the input parameter is email I don't want null values in the `u.Email` column.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your where condition as below

```
where 
a.Active = 1
and (
     (@Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumber is not null)
     or 
     (@Method = 'email' and u.Email is not null)
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

you not need to use case when in where you can use

```
where 
a.Active = 1
and

-- This part now work
(
    (@Method = 'phone' and u.PhoneNumber is not null) OR
    (@Method = 'email' and u.Email is not null)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

it's like your select statement

```
where 
a.Active = 1
and
case 
    when @Method = 'phone' then u.PhoneNumber 
    when @Method = 'email' then u.Email 
end is not null
```